# Why is the 4 rakat Sunnah before Asr and Isha not included in the hadith?

Tags: salat, hadith

In this hadith:
"Allaah will build a house in Heaven for whoever is diligent in observing 12 Sunnah Rak'aat (as follows): 4 Rak'aat before and 2 after the Dhuhr (Midday) Prayer, 2 after the Maghrib (Sunset Prayer), 2 after the Ishaa (Evening) Prayer and 2 before the Fajr (Dawn) Prayer." 
Hadith sahih narrated by at-Tirmidhi No. 379 and by others. Hadith No. 6183 in Sahih al-Jaami.

Why is the 4 rakat Sunnah before Asr and Isha not included? Normally in prayer schemes these two are present but according to this hadith they are not.

Comment: You should explain why you expect it to be included? There are a variety of ahadith about recomended nafl (optional) prayers.

Comment: If you have two accounts consider [merging them](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and stop posting with a non-registered account and editing with a registred one.

Comment: Prayer schems are madhhab related. Different madhhabs have different opinions on what is sunnah or nafl and what isn't.

Comment: I have two accounts for different things but I dont know how to merge them.

Comment: The link I've provided tells you how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer.

The Asr (Late-Afternoon) Prayer has no routine Sunnah (basic recommended voluntary prayer). However, it is mustahab (preferable and recommended) that one prays 4 Rak'aat before the Asr Prayer. The 4 Rak'ahs are of less reward and significance in importance of adhering to them compared to the "sunnan al-rawaatib" described above. The 4 Rak'ahs are the ones intended by the Prophet (May peace and blessings be upon him) in saying: "May Allaah have mercy on one who prays 4 rakaaat before the Asr Prayer." Narrated by at-Tirmidhi no. 395 and he declared it a hassan and ghareeb Hadith. Al-Albany rated the Hadith as hassan in Sahih al-Jami No. 3493.
All the foregoing 4-Rak'ah voluntary prayers are to be prayed two at a time according to Imam ash-Shafii and Imam Ahmad.